# Combine index-based and logical addressing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance

Consider a matrix `X`. I have to update a submatrix of `X`, `X(row1:row2, col1:col2)`, with a matrix Z (of size `row2-row1+1`, `col2-col1+1`) but only on those positions where a logical matrix `L` (of size `row2-row1+1`, `col2-col1+1`) is true.

E.g. if

```
 X=[ 1  2  3  4  5  6
    11 12 13 14 15 16
    21 22 23 24 25 26
    31 32 33 34 34 36]
 Z=[31 41
    32 42]
 L=[ 1 0
     0 1]
 row1 = 2; row2 = 3; col1 = 3; col2 = 4
```

then after the update I should get:

```
 X=[ 1  2  3  4  5  6
    11 12 31 14 15 16
    21 22 23 42 25 26
    31 32 33 34 34 36]
```

Currently I do the following:

```
Y = X(row1:row2, col1:col2);
Y(L) = Z(L); 
X(row1:row2, col1:col2) = Y;
```

This code is in a tight loop and according to Matlab's (v2019a) profiler is the main bottleneck of my program. In the real code `X` is a 2000x1500x3 cube; `row1`, `row2`, `col1`, `col2`, `Z` and `L` change in the loop.

The question is whether it can be rewritten into a single / faster assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: Since `L` has size `row2-row1+1, col2-col1+1`, the statement `Y(L) = Z(L)` does not select the submatrix you describe. Can you calrify? Also, what is `Z`?

Comment: What Matlab version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, without seeing your actual code, I get the sense that your solution *may* be as fast as you can get. The reason I say that is because I tested a few different solutions by creating some random sample data closer to your actual problem. I assumed `X` is an image of type `uint8` with size 2000-by-1500-by-3, `Z` is size `N`-by-`N` (i.e. we will only be modifying the first page of `X`), `L` is an `N`-by-`N` logical array, and the row and column indices are randomly chosen:

```
X = randi([0 255], 2000, 1500, 3, 'uint8');
N = 20;  % Submatrix size
Z = randi([0 255], N, N, 'uint8');
L = (rand(N, N) > 0.5);
row1 = randi([1 2000-N]);
row2 = row1+N-1
col1 = randi([1 1500-N]);
col2 = col1+N-1;
```

I then tested 3 different solutions: your original solution, a solution using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to create a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2) for `X`, and a solution that creates a logical index for `X`:

```
% Original solution:
Y = X(row1:row2, col1:col2, 1);
Y(L) = Z(L);
X(row1:row2, col1:col2, 1) = Y;

% Linear index solution:
[rIndex, cIndex] = find(L);
X(sub2ind(size(X), rIndex+row1-1, cIndex+col1-1)) = Z(L);

% Logical index solution
[R, C, ~] = size(X);
fullL = false(R, C);
fullL(row1:row2, col1:col2) = L;
X(fullL) = Z(L);
```

I tested these repeatedly with randomly-generated sample data using [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) and found that your original solution is consistently the fastest. The linear index solution is very close, but slightly slower. The logical index solution takes more than twice as long.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define some example data:

```
X = randi(9,5,6);
Y = 10+X;
row1 = 2;
row2 = 4;
col1 = 3;
col2 = 4;
L = logical([0 1; 0 0; 1 1]);
```

Then:

```
ind_subm = bsxfun(@plus, (row1:row2).',size(X,1)*((col1:col2)-1));
    % linear index for submatrix
ind_subm_masked = ind_subm(L);
    % linear index for masked submatrix
X(ind_subm_masked) = Y(ind_subm_masked);
```

Example results:

- `X` before:

  ```
  X =
       6     2     1     7     9     6
       3     3     3     5     5     7
       6     3     8     6     5     4
       7     4     1     3     3     4
       2     5     9     5     5     9
  ```
- `L`:

  ```
  L =
    3×2 logical array
     0   1
     0   0
     1   1
  ```
- `X` after:

  ```
  X =
       6     2     1     7     9     6
       3     3     3    15     5     7
       6     3     8     6     5     4
       7     4    11    13     3     4
       2     5     9     5     5     9
  ```